# Synchronize Power BI with Git

Tags: git, powerbi

Is it possible to somehow make a synchronization between Power BI and Git?

I mean I need to track if someone made changes in DAX or Power Query and put it to the Git status or make a new automatic commit whatever, but somehow track such actions.

Is it possible to implement?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with BIM files if you create your model in Tabular Editor, but it probably won’t be of too much use.

PBIX files are not suitable for this, but you can also rename to zip and extract a gnarly XML with DAX components and such to diff the data in GitHub, but that sounds like a nightmare to me.